# Hartl Chapter 9.2

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Getting this error, main message being: **undefined local variable or method 'user' for SessionsController**, singling out line 10 under 'create' in said controller in each case .

Now I have found my own fix to the problem, which is changing the line 'redirect_back_or user' to 'redirect_back_or @user' in the Session Controller(line 10). However this goes against Hartl's directions, as 'redirect_back_or user' is explicit in the instructions.

Wondering if there is an error I made somewhere else that, if fixed, would let 'redirect_back_or user' work properly.

```
 ERROR["test_successful_edit_with_friendly_forwarding", UsersEditTest, 2016-02-10 03:42:25 -0500]
 test_successful_edit_with_friendly_forwarding#UsersEditTest (1455093745.41s)
NameError:         NameError: undefined local variable or method `user' for #<SessionsController:0x007fc46b54ed40>
            app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb:10:in `create'
            test/test_helper.rb:23:in `log_in_as'
            test/integration/users_edit_test.rb:21:in `block in <class:UsersEditTest>'
        app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb:10:in `create'
        test/test_helper.rb:23:in `log_in_as'
        test/integration/users_edit_test.rb:21:in `block in <class:UsersEditTest>'

ERROR["test_unsuccessful_edit", UsersEditTest, 2016-02-10 03:42:25 -0500]
 test_unsuccessful_edit#UsersEditTest (1455093745.44s)
NameError:         NameError: undefined local variable or method `user' for #<SessionsController:0x007fc4701e7530>
            app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb:10:in `create'
            test/test_helper.rb:23:in `log_in_as'
            test/integration/users_edit_test.rb:9:in `block in <class:UsersEditTest>'
        app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb:10:in `create'
        test/test_helper.rb:23:in `log_in_as'
        test/integration/users_edit_test.rb:9:in `block in <class:UsersEditTest>'

ERROR["test_login_with_remembering", UsersLoginTest, 2016-02-10 03:42:25 -0500]
 test_login_with_remembering#UsersLoginTest (1455093745.64s)
NameError:         NameError: undefined local variable or method `user' for #<SessionsController:0x007fc471c04d78>
            app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb:10:in `create'
            test/test_helper.rb:23:in `log_in_as'
            test/integration/users_login_test.rb:50:in `block in <class:UsersLoginTest>'
        app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb:10:in `create'
        test/test_helper.rb:23:in `log_in_as'
        test/integration/users_login_test.rb:50:in `block in <class:UsersLoginTest>'

ERROR["test_login_without_remembering", UsersLoginTest, 2016-02-10 03:42:25 -0500]
 test_login_without_remembering#UsersLoginTest (1455093745.68s)
NameError:         NameError: undefined local variable or method `user' for #<SessionsController:0x007fc46b9ce370>
            app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb:10:in `create'
            test/test_helper.rb:23:in `log_in_as'
            test/integration/users_login_test.rb:55:in `block in <class:UsersLoginTest>'
        app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb:10:in `create'
        test/test_helper.rb:23:in `log_in_as'
        test/integration/users_login_test.rb:55:in `block in <class:UsersLoginTest>'

ERROR["test_login_with_valid_information_followed_by_logout", UsersLoginTest, 2016-02-10 03:42:25 -0500]
 test_login_with_valid_information_followed_by_logout#UsersLoginTest (1455093745.71s)
NameError:         NameError: undefined local variable or method `user' for #<SessionsController:0x007fc47096d4f8>
            app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb:10:in `create'
            test/integration/users_login_test.rb:31:in `block in <class:UsersLoginTest>'
        app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb:10:in `create'
        test/integration/users_login_test.rb:31:in `block in <class:UsersLoginTest>'

ERROR["test_login_with_valid_information", UsersLoginTest, 2016-02-10 03:42:25 -0500]
 test_login_with_valid_information#UsersLoginTest (1455093745.74s)
NameError:         NameError: undefined local variable or method `user' for #<SessionsController:0x007fc471ba7f10>
            app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb:10:in `create'
            test/integration/users_login_test.rb:20:in `block in <class:UsersLoginTest>'
        app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb:10:in `create'
        test/integration/users_login_test.rb:20:in `block in <class:UsersLoginTest>'
```

Sessions Controller

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)
    if @user && @user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
      log_in @user
      params[:session][:remember_me] == '1' ? remember(@user) : forget(@user)
      redirect_back_or user
    else
      flash.now[:danger] = 'Invalid email/password combination'
    render 'new'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    log_out if logged_in?
    redirect_to root_url
  end
end
```

Sessions Helper

```
# Returns the user corresponding to the remember token cookie
     def current_user
    if (user_id = session[:user_id])
      @current_user ||= User.find_by(id: user_id)
    elsif (user_id = cookies.signed[:user_id])
      user = User.find_by(id: user_id)
      if user && user.authenticated?(cookies[:remember_token])
        log_in user
        @current_user = user
      end
    end
  end


    # Returns true if the user is logged in, false otherwise
    def logged_in?
        !current_user.nil?
    end

    # Forgets a persistent session
    def forget(user)
        user.forget
        cookies.delete(:user_id)
        cookies.delete(:remember_token)
    end

    # Logs out current user
    def log_out
        forget(current_user)
        session.delete(:user_id)
        @current_user = nil
    end

     # Redirects to stored location (or to the default).
  def redirect_back_or(default)
    redirect_to(session[:forwarding_url] || default)
    session.delete(:forwarding_url)
  end

  # Stores the URL trying to be accessed.
  def store_location
    session[:forwarding_url] = request.url if request.get?
  end
end
```

Users Login Test

```
require 'test_helper'

class UsersLoginTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
    def setup
        @user = users(:michael)
    end

    test "login with invalid information" do
        get login_path
        assert_template 'sessions/new'
        post login_path, session: { email: "", password: "" }
        assert_template 'sessions/new'
        assert_not flash.empty?
        get root_path
        assert flash.empty?
    end

  test "login with valid information" do
        get login_path
        post login_path, session: { email: @user.email, password: 'password' }
        assert_redirected_to @user
        follow_redirect!
        assert_template 'users/show'
        assert_select "a[href=?]", login_path, count: 0
        assert_select "a[href=?]", logout_path
        assert_select "a[href=?]", user_path(@user)
    end

   test "login with valid information followed by logout" do
    get login_path
    post login_path, session: { email: @user.email, password: 'password' }
    assert is_logged_in?
    assert_redirected_to @user
    follow_redirect!
    assert_template 'users/show'
    assert_select "a[href=?]", login_path, count: 0
    assert_select "a[href=?]", logout_path
    assert_select "a[href=?]", user_path(@user)
    delete logout_path
    assert_not is_logged_in?
    assert_redirected_to root_url
     # Simulate a user logging out in a second window
    delete logout_path
    follow_redirect!
    assert_select "a[href=?]", login_path
    assert_select "a[href=?]", logout_path,      count: 0
    assert_select "a[href=?]", user_path(@user), count: 0
  end
test "login with remembering" do
    log_in_as(@user, remember_me: '1')
    assert_equal cookies['remember_token'], assigns(:user).remember_token
  end

  test "login without remembering" do
    log_in_as(@user, remember_me: '0')
    assert_nil cookies['remember_token']
  end
end
```

Users Edit Test

```
require 'test_helper'

class UsersEditTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  def setup
    @user = users(:michael)
  end

  test "unsuccessful edit" do
    log_in_as(@user)
    get edit_user_path(@user)
    assert_template 'users/edit'
    patch user_path(@user), user: { name:  "",
                                    email: "foo@invalid",
                                    password:              "foo",
                                    password_confirmation: "bar" }
    assert_template 'users/edit'
  end

  test "successful edit with friendly forwarding" do
    get edit_user_path(@user)
    log_in_as(@user)
    assert_redirected_to edit_user_path(@user)
    name  = "Foo Bar"
    email = "foo@bar.com"
    patch user_path(@user), user: { name:  name,
                                    email: email,
                                    password:              "",
                                    password_confirmation: "" }
    assert_not flash.empty?
    assert_redirected_to @user
    @user.reload
    assert_equal name,  @user.name
    assert_equal email, @user.email
  end


end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your sessions controller, try changing your `@user` instance variable under the `create` action, to `user` throughout.

```
user = User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
      if user.activated?
        log_in user
        params[:session][:remember_me] == '1' ? remember(user) : forget(user)
        redirect_back_or user
      else
```

Then run the test and see if the errors still happen.